# Differential steering

Tags: differential-drive, steering

I'm hoping to build a 40kg rover for running on soft and loose dirt by using fewer than 4 motors. Does anyone know if differential steering is possible on 3 actuated wheels? That is, two at the front and one at the back.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: why would it not be possible? ... it is unclear what the 3rd wheel would be doing

Comment: Indeed. What should the 3rd wheel be doing whilst turning? I can't seem to find an implementation of 3 wheel differential steering though.

Comment: perhaps a double mecanum wheel would work on the third wheel

Comment: [This image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tanklike.png) from the [Wikipedia page on "differential steering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_steering) shows clearly that your project is doable with only 2 actuated wheels. The number of motors depends on the design choices regarding the transmission.

Comment: @virolino Yes, I appreciate that it can be done with 2 actuated wheels. But I'm looking to have 3 actuated wheels for better traction.

Comment: Make the 3rd wheel spin also using a motor. If you calculate motions properly, it might actually help - but you have the risk that it will occasionally push the robot in the undesired direction, since its swiveling is not controlled.. But you can verify the swivel position, and adjust the power to the 3rd wheel accordingly. Maybe adjust the power to the other 2 wheels too.